# How to put margin on ScopeBar in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

[image]

As you can see, Button "Back" overlapping on ScopeBar. i have tried googled a lot, but still not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I came across a similar issue with Table View, and found this helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1 and, Check the topic: **Add a Segue to Navigate Forward**

Comment: instead of navigation . theres no solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure. My issue was solved by the way it was instructed in the link I provided, and I was satisfied with it. I'm a beginner myself, and will let you know if I come across anything.

Comment: btw. if im using those navigation theres no issue for me haha. thanks :)

Comment: Oh! that's nice! :)